# Creating a censor program - infile to outfile

Tags: python

I am working on creating a censor program that takes a txt file and replaces all 4 letter words with **** and then the new text with the censored words is saved to the outfile. With this I am printing the infile with the censored words but it is not saving to the outfile. I am new to this and am having trouble figuring out what I'm missing to get it to print to the outfile. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
def censor():      
    
    infile = open("word.list.txt", "r")
    outfile = open("new.word.list1", "w")


    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if len(word) == 4:
                print ("****")
            else:
                print (word)
                print(line.rstrip(), file=outfile)

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

censor()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question . You should show an example of the input, the desired output, the actual output, and explain how that output is wrong. You should also try to think clearly about your intended logic. For example: when you write `for word in words:`, what do you expect the value of `word` to be? *each time through that loop*, what are the possibilities for what should get written to the file? Now, look at your `print` statements. Which ones write to the file? Why?

Comment: (Hint: when you add `, file=outfile` to the `print` function call, what do you think that means?)

Answer (score 0):

you need an empty array that will store the new line each line, then edit them the way you want. Then after that you just push the new line to the outfile

```py
def censor():      
    
    infile = open("word.list.txt", "r")
    outfile = open("new.word.list1", "w")


    for line in infile:
        words = line.split()
        newline=[]
        for word in words:
            if len(word) == 4:
                newline.append("****")
            else:
                newline.append(word.rstrip())

        print(" ".join(newline), file=outfile)        

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

censor()
```

Comment: We call that a *list* in Python, and it is definitely not necessary for solving the problem. This also doesn't help explain the problem with the original code.